# Does Jenkins prohibit LDAP manager to login

Tags: jenkins

Trying to get LDAP security checking working with Jenkins.
When I try to login to Jenkins, using the same username/pw as the :manager" username and pw, I get....

Login
Authentication: failed for user "me@mycompany.com"
Lookup
User lookup: user "me@mycompany.com" does not exist.
Does the Manager Dn have permissions to perform user lookup?
Are the user search base and user search filter settings correct?
LDAP Group lookup: could not verify.
Please try with a user that is a member of at least one LDAP group.
Lockout
The user "me@mycompany.com" will be unable to login with the supplied password.
If this is your own account this would mean you would be locked out!
Are you sure you want to save this configuration?

There's nothing wrong with the username and pw.  BUT, it is the same as the manager's username and pw.

? What is the meaning of that second part of the message (The user ... will be unable to login with...)

? Is the lockout warning because the "manager" in the LDAP setup is the same username/pw as what I'm trying to login with?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does allow the manager to also login as a user.
If LDAP settings being tested are such that it would prohibit the manager from logging in, then you get the potential lockout message/warning when you test the settings. For example, if the user search filter will only allow users in group xyz, and if the manager is not in group xyz, then you have a lockout.